# Manage a group using the Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I am new to Facebook application development i want to know if it possible to manage a group trought the Facebook Api? i Want to remove members if necessary trought the app but i cant find any materials that can help me on this

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/members#delete

You can only remove users from App groups, i am sure you are not talking about those.

In general: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group